# Good, reliable function to get file extension

Tags: php, filenames

I have made a function that so far seems to be really good at getting the file extension no matter how strange the file name is. Every method I have come across on the net seems to like using explode on the . to get the extension, but what if the file name has multiple .s in it?

Here is my function:

```
$fileName = 'my.reallyAwk-ward..file--name.JPEG' ;
echo getExtension($fileName) ;

function getExtension($fileName)
{
    $ext = explode('.', strrev($fileName), 2) ;
    $ext = strtolower(strrev($ext[0])) ;
    return $ext ;
}
```

Am I reinventing a wheel or can this be made more efficient?

Comment: It looks good; you could also check if there are multiple extensions, and return an array in that case, though that doesn't seem to be what you are looking for. However, a file such as `name.php.inc` does count as having two extensions.

Comment: FYI an `explode()` and `end()` would also do what you want, but `pathinfo` may contain more useful info. @AndreiBârsan No a file cannot have multiple extensions. The extension of a file called `name.php.inc` has the extension `.inc` and a filename of `name.php`.

Comment: I know about pathinfo but I just want something a little simpler to bring back the extension only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: Just specifying PATHINFO_EXTENSION does the trick. pathinfo is also a little faster than Everts and my function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is slightly cleaner:

```
$filename = 'myfile.jpg';
$extension = substr($filename, strrpos($filename,'.') +1 )
```

Exploding creates a new array, and there's a lot more 'work' in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as well.

```
echo substr(strrchr('file.txt','.'),1);
```